# Not sure hot to use validate_arithmetic function to check the data type

Tags: python

```
from goody import irange
from goody import type_as_str

import math
from _ast import Num

class Fraction:
    @staticmethod
    # Call as Fraction._gcd(...); no self parameter
    # Helper method computes the Greatest Common Divisor of x and y
    def _gcd(x : int, y : int) -> int:
        assert x >= 0 and y >= 0, 'Fraction._gcd: x('+str(x)+') and y('+str(y)+') must be >= 0'
        while y != 0:
            x, y = y, x % y
        return x

    # Returns a string that is the decimal representation of a Fraction, with
    #   decimal_places digitst appearing after the decimal points.
    # For example: if x = Fraction(23,8), then x(5) returns '2.75000'
    def __call__(self, decimal_places):
        answer = ''
        num = self.num
        denom = self.denom

        # handle negative values
        if num < 0:
            num, answer = -num, '-'

        # handle integer part
        if num >= denom:
            answer += str(num//denom)
            num     = num - num//denom*denom

        # handle decimal part
        answer += '.'+str(num*10**decimal_places//denom)
        return answer

    @staticmethod
    # Call as Fraction._validate_arithmetic(..); with no self parameter
    # Helper method raises exception with appropriate message if type(v) is not
    #   in the set of types t; the message includes the values of the strings
    #   op (operator), lt (left type) and rt (right type)
    # An example call (from my __add__ method), which checks whether the type of
    #   right is a Fraction or int is...
    # Fraction._validate_arithmetic(right, {Fraction,int},'+','Fraction',type_as_str(right))


    def _validate_arithmetic(v, t : set, op : str, lt : str, rt : str):
        if type(v) not in t:
            raise TypeError('unsupported operand type(s) for '+op+
                            ': \''+lt+'\' and \''+rt+'\'')        

    @staticmethod
    # Call as Fraction._validate_relational(..); with no self parameter
    # Helper method raises exception with appropriate message if type(v) is not
    #   in the set of types t; the message includes the values of the strings
    #   op (operator), and rt (right type)


    def _validate_relational(v, t : set, op : str, rt : str):
        if type(v) not in t:
            raise TypeError('unorderable types: '+
                            'Fraction() '+op+' '+rt+'()')        


    def __init__(self,num=0,denom=1):

        self.num = num 
        self.denom = denom 
        if self.denom < 0:
            self.denom = -self.denom 
            self.num = -self.num 
        if self.num == 0:
            self.denom = 1
        if type(self.num)!= int or type(self.denom)!= int:
            raise AssertionError
        from fractions import gcd
        f = gcd(self.denom,self.num)
        int(f)
        if f < 0:
            f = -f
        self.denom = self.denom/f 
        self.num = self.num /f
        self.denom = int(self.denom)
        self.num = int(self.num)



    def __repr__(self):
        s = 'Fraction' + str(('('+str(self.num)+','+str(self.denom)+')'))
        return s


    def __str__(self):
        s = str(self.num) +'/'+ str(self.denom)
        return s



    def __bool__(self):
        if self.num/self.denom == 0:
            return False
        else:
            return True



    def __getitem__(self,i):
        if i == 0 or i[0] == 'n':
            return self.num
        elif i ==1 or i[0]=='d':
            return self.denom
        else:
            raise TypeError



    def __pos__(self):
        s = str(self.num)+'/'+str(self.denom)
        return s



    def __neg__(self):
        s = str(-1*self.num)+'/'+str(self.denom)
        return s



    def __abs__(self):
        if self.num/self.denom > 0:
            s = str(self.num)+'/'+str(self.denom)
            return s

        else:
            s = str( -1*self.num)+'/'+str(self.denom)
            return s



    def __add__(self,right):
        Fraction._validate_arithmetic(right, {Fraction,int},'+','Fraction',type_as_str(right))
        from fractions import Fraction
        s = Fraction(self.num,self.denom) + Fraction(str(right))
        return s

    def __radd__(self,left):
        from fractions import Fraction
        s = Fraction(self.num,self.denom) + Fraction(str(left))
        return s


    def __sub__(self,right):
        from fractions import Fraction
        s = Fraction(self.num,self.denom) - Fraction(str(right))
        return s

    def __rsub__(self,left):
        from fractions import Fraction
        s = Fraction(self.num,self.denom) - Fraction(str(left))
        return s


    def __mul__(self,right):
        from fractions import Fraction
        s = Fraction(self.num,self.denom) * Fraction(str(right))
        return s

    def __rmul__(self,left):
        from fractions import Fraction
        s = Fraction(self.num,self.denom) * Fraction(str(left))
        return s


    def __truediv__(self,right):
        from fractions import Fraction
        s = Fraction(self.num,self.denom) / Fraction(str(right))
        return s

    def __rtruediv__(self,left):
        from fractions import Fraction
        s = Fraction(self.num,self.denom) / Fraction(str(left))
        return s

    def __pow__(self,right):
        from fractions import Fraction
        import math 
        s = Fraction(pow(self.num/self.denom,right))
        return s



    def __eq__(self,right):
        from fractions import Fraction
        return (Fraction(self.num,self.denom) == Fraction(str(right)))




    def __lt__(self,right):
        from fractions import Fraction
        return (Fraction(self.num,self.denom) < Fraction(str(right)))



    def __gt__(self,right):
        from fractions import Fraction
        return (Fraction(self.num,self.denom) > Fraction(str(right)))

    #Uncomment this method when you are ready to write/test it
    #If this is pass, then no attributes will be set!
    #def __setattr__(self,name,value):
     #   pass







# Newton: pi = 6*arcsin(1/2); see the arcsin series at http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/54137.html
```

## Check your results at http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~huberty/math5337/groupe/digits.html

## also see http://www.numberworld.org/misc_runs/pi-5t/details.html

```
def compute_pi(n):
    def prod(r):
        answer = 1
        for i in r:
            answer *= i
        return answer

    answer = Fraction(1,2)
    x      = Fraction(1,2)
    for i in irange(1,n):
        big    = 2*i+1
        answer += Fraction(prod(range(1,big,2)),prod(range(2,big,2)))*x**big/big       
    return 6*answer





if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Put in simple tests for Fraction before allowing driver to run

    print()
    import driver

    driver.default_file_name = 'bsc1.txt'
#     driver.default_show_traceback= True
#     driver.default_show_exception= True
#     driver.default_show_exception_message= True
    driver.driver()
```

ok, I just have a question about how to call the function validate_arithmetic. I added the whole thing to help to understand. I need to call the function validate_arithmetic to check whether the parameter 'right' and 'left' are Fraction. The function validate_arithmetic needs to be called form function **add** to function **gt**.  I added function validate_arithmetic only to the the first **add** function to show the result:

```
63 # __add__/__radd__
65 *Error: f+Frac(1,3) raised exception UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Fraction' referenced before assignment
66 *Error: f+2 raised exception UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Fraction' referenced before assignment
67 *Error: Frac(1,3)+f raised exception UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Fraction' referenced before assignment
71 *Error: f+1. raised wrong exception(UnboundLocalError) should be from list: TypeError
72 *Error: 1.+f failed to raise exception from list: TypeError
73 # __sub__/__rsub__
77 *Error: 2-f -> -3/2 but should -> 3/2
80 *Error: f-1. failed to raise exception from list: TypeError
81 *Error: 1.-f failed to raise exception from list: TypeError
82 # __mul__/__rmul__
90 *Error: f*1. failed to raise exception from list: TypeError
91 *Error: 1.*f failed to raise exception from list: TypeError
92 # __truediv__/__rtruediv__
94 *Error: 3/f -> 1/6 but should -> 6/1
96 *Error: 3/Frac(1,3) -> 1/9 but should -> 9/1
100 *Error: f/1. failed to raise exception from list: TypeError
101 *Error: 1./f failed to raise exception from list: TypeError
102 # __pow__
107 *Error: f**3. failed to raise exception from list: TypeError
109 # Compute pi (lots of arithmetic calculation)
110 *Error: fraction.compute_pi(5) raised exception UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Fraction' referenced before assignment
111 *Error: fraction.compute_pi(20) raised exception UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Fraction' referenced before assignment
112 *Error: fraction.compute_pi(50)(50) raised exception UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Fraction' referenced before assignment
113 #  ==
120 *Error: a==1. failed to raise exception from list: TypeError
121 *Error: 1.==a failed to raise exception from list: TypeError
122 #  !=
127 *Error: a!=1. failed to raise exception from list: TypeError
128 *Error: 1.!=a failed to raise exception from list: TypeError
129 #  <
134 *Error: a<1. failed to raise exception from list: TypeError
135 *Error: 1.<a failed to raise exception from list: TypeError
136 #  >
141 *Error: a>1. failed to raise exception from list: TypeError
142 *Error: 1.>a failed to raise exception from list: TypeError
145 # __setattr__ (assuming instance variables are named num and denom)
146 *Error: f.num = 1 failed to raise exception from list: NameError
```

I get the Error local variable 'Fraction' referenced before assignment. However, if I put

```
Fraction._validate_arithmetic(right, {Fraction,int},'+','Fraction',type_as_str(right))
```

under the line

```
from fractions import Fraction
```

which becomes

```
def __add__(self,right):
    from fractions import Fraction
    Fraction._validate_arithmetic(right, {Fraction,int},'+','Fraction',type_as_str(right))
    s = Fraction(self.num,self.denom) + Fraction(str(right))
    return s
```

I get the following Error

```
63 # __add__/__radd__
65 *Error: f+Frac(1,3) raised exception AttributeError: type object 'Fraction' has no attribute '_validate_arithmetic'
66 *Error: f+2 raised exception AttributeError: type object 'Fraction' has no attribute '_validate_arithmetic'
67 *Error: Frac(1,3)+f raised exception AttributeError: type object 'Fraction' has no attribute '_validate_arithmetic'
71 *Error: f+1. raised wrong exception(AttributeError) should be from list: TypeError
72 *Error: 1.+f failed to raise exception from list: TypeError
```

anyway, How  can I call the function ._validate_arithmetic in the correct way? or to find out another way to eliminate the "failed to raise exception from list: TypeError" ? Can anyone help me to fix it?
(by the way the input is always Frac(1,2))

Comment: Try to provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: You define class `Fraction` and you import class `Fraction` from other module at the same time.